error: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letters
#define enable_rdpmc() ({ 
unsigned long cr4; 
asm volatile( 
"push %rax\n\t" 
"mov %%cr4, %0\n\t" 
"or $(0x100), %0\n\t" 
"mov %0, %%cr4\n\t" 
"pop %rax" 
: "=r" (cr4) 
: 
: "memory"); })
Iam trying to build this but it is pushing errors and iam debugging it is throwing signal illegal termination

I suspect the problem lies in %rax that would required double %% instead in inline asm Inline assembly : register referencing conventions .. but as a side note I'm not sure you really needed to push and pop that register since it shouldn't change its value in the meanwhile. OT: it sounds suspicious you need to do something like that but you are not familiar with the basics
